# DB2 UPGRADE DB “SQL0954C Not enough storage space is available in the application heap to process the statement. SQLSTATE=57011”

Tags: db2, upgrade, db2-luw

I’m attempting to upgrade DB2 10.5 to 11.1 and when I’m doing the DB2 UPGRADE on my database. I’m constantly getting a

> SQL0954C Not enough storage space is available in the application heap to process the statement. SQLSTATE=57011

I have increased my APPLHEAPSZ and APPL_MEMORY to match my INSTANCE_MEMORY of AUTOMATIC(2449536) (and tried various other sizes in between) and I still get the error.

If I run a `DB2MTRK -a` command, I can see my apph memory increase to 4.8G before throwing the error. I am by no means a DB2 expert, so I’m assuming I’m probably doing something obviously wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22012894 suggest using a value of 8000 or 32000 ..  but open a case with IBM Support if you can.  BTW what fixlevel of DB2 11.1 are you upgrading to?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following before the next attempt:

```
db2 update db cfg for MYDB using APPLHEAPSZ automatic APPL_MEMORY automatic SELF_TUNING_MEM ON
```

If they are set as described already, then try to free some memory for APPLHEAPSZ / APPL_MEMORY growth by constraining the size of bufferpools:

```
db2set DB2_OVERRIDE_BPF=10000
db2stop
db2start
```

Don't forget to reset this variable afterwards:

```
db2set DB2_OVERRIDE_BPF=
db2stop
db2start
```

If it still fails, it's good to look at the corresponding messages in the db2diag.log

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I tried this, but still no success. Here is the entry from my log:

2018-11-08-15.48.48.612000-300 I5495453F1112        LEVEL: Warning

PID     : 2792                 TID : 1460           PROC : db2syscs.exe

INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000           DB   : MYDB

APPHDL  : 0-8                  APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.181108203254

AUTHID  : DB2ADMIN             HOSTNAME: WIN-5MC66HH7NA4

EDUID   : 1460                 EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDB) 0

FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, SQO Memory Management, SqloMemController::requestMemory, probe:50

MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8B0F0000=-1961951232=SQLO_NOMEM "No Memory Available"
          DIA8300C A memory heap error has occurred.

DATA #1 : String, 36 bytes
OOM - Instance memory request failed

DATA #2 : String, 35 bytes
Logging disabled until next success

DATA #3 : unsigned integer, 8 bytes
5148573696

DATA #4 : unsigned integer, 8 bytes
0

DATA #5 : String, 13 bytes
APPL-MYDB

DATA #6 : unsigned integer, 8 bytes
6909722624

DATA #7 : unsigned integer, 8 bytes
3475243008

DATA #8 : unsigned integer, 8 bytes
9480896512

DATA #9 : unsigned integer, 8 bytes
10033299456

DATA #10: unsigned integer, 8 bytes
3825991680

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a Case with IBM.

Comment: Looks like the solution was adding more RAM to the VM. Thanks for your help.